# Insert new child node in an existing XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Good day everyone. I would like to ask for help with my code. I have here an XML document containing the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TechnicalReport>
      <Data quantity = "2" description ="myDesc" findings = "none" actiontaken = "none" />
    </TechnicalReport>
```

What I would like to do here is to add another child node inside the . I have searched for so many websites about my problem but to no avail. For example, I will add another node, say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TechnicalReport>
      <Data quantity = "2" description ="myDesc" findings = "none" actiontaken = "none" />
      <Data quantity = "3" description ="myDesc2" findings = "none2" actiontaken = "none3" />
    </TechnicalReport>
```

I have successfully compiled and loaded the XML file into a Repeater control using an XMLDataSource, but when I do an insert from my form, the Repeater control does not update its contents, and even my XML file also does not update.

Here's my C# code:

```
public void AddNewRecord()
{
    //Load XML Schema
    XmlDocument originalXml = new XmlDocument();
    originalXml.Load(Server.MapPath("xmlTechReportDetails.xml"));

    //Create the node name Technical Report
    XmlNode TechReport = originalXml.SelectSingleNode("TechnicalReport");
    XmlNode Data = originalXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Data", null);

    //Insert quantity
    XmlAttribute quantity = originalXml.CreateAttribute("quantity");
    quantity.Value = txtQty.Text;

    //Insert description
    XmlAttribute description = originalXml.CreateAttribute("description");
    description.Value = txtDescription.Text;

    //Insert findings
    XmlAttribute findings = originalXml.CreateAttribute("findings");
    findings.Value = txtFindings.Text;

    //Insert actions taken.
    XmlAttribute actionTaken = originalXml.CreateAttribute("actiontaken");
    actionTaken.Value = txtAction.Text;

    Data.Attributes.Append(quantity);
    Data.Attributes.Append(description);
    Data.Attributes.Append(findings);
    Data.Attributes.Append(actionTaken);

    TechReport.AppendChild(Data);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Where are you set `XMLDataSouece`?

Comment: It is already set at Design Time.

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlTechReportDetails" runat="server" 
     DataFile = "~/Administrator/xmlTechReportDetails.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

Comment: I think you must get XML to which bound your control using `Data` property, modify it and set back.

Comment: Get `XmlTechReportDetails.Data` as string, parse it as `XML`, modify and set it back as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this at the end of your method:

```
originalXml.Save(Server.MapPath("xmlTechReportDetails.xml"));
```

I think it's because you did not save the file. That's why your changes are not retained.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
//Create the node name Technical Report
XmlNode TechReport = originalXml.SelectSingleNode("TechnicalReport");
```

Use this code

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = originalXml.GetElementsByTagName("connectionStrings");
```